# Want to make gradient background in my navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to make gradient background in my navigation bar with two colors one half with light blue and other half with dark blue.

This is what I have tried so far,

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)]; 
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer]; 
gradient.frame = view.bounds; 
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], 
                                            (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], 
                                            nil]; 
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: here comes the standard question: What have you tried?  We aren't here to write code for you, we're here to help you if you have any issues with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a custom look for navigation bar I will advice to create a image and set it as the background image of UINavigationBar using the method below.

```
 - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Better will be to use UINavigationBar appearance to apply it to all the UINavigationControllers used with in the app.

Comment: Hey can we use CAGradientLayer class in this other than creating an image ?

Comment: I have never tried it. But i think you can give it a try you can subclass UINavigationBar and use UINavigationController init method - (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass and in UINavigationBar you can add CAGradientLayer.

Comment: Thanks a lot will definitely try this.